# ElasticSearch - Multiple types sharing the same child type

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for some help with ElasticSearch involving multiple "parent" types sharing the same "child" type.

As a trivial example, let's say I have two parent types:

1. blogEntry
2. status

I'd like to have a single "comment" type which is a child of both "blogEntry" and "status", since users can comment on both blog entries and users' status updates.

Is this actually possible in ES?

*Or*, am I looking at this problem in the wrong way? Does parent-child make no sense here, and instead would I want to use nested objects?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure if you wan't a single comment document to be linked to both blog and status aka have two parent documents if so that is not possible if not why not just create two separate types `comment_status` and `comment_blog` and use [templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) to ensure they share same mapping.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment:

- The parent child [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html) does not allow to specify multiple parents
- Lets say if you have 2 parents which are routed to different shards,
  which shard will the child document be routed to?

You could instead have one child as nested document to the parent and the more frequently changing one as an actual child referencing the parent type.